# How does Git store directory information？

Tags: git

I always wonder how Git stores directories, does Git following Linux's philosophy "anything is a FILE", then see directory as file to store?

Comment: A directory is mapped to a tree object. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 5):

While [AtnNn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63734643/1256452) is correct in terms of how the internal storage works, it's worth noting that Git *builds* these tree objects from the thing that Git calls its *index* or *staging area* or (rarely now) *cache*.  The index is not capable of holding directories: it holds only files.  The files in the index simply have long path names with embedded slashes, such as `path/to/file.txt`.

The `git write-tree` command reads through the index and splits this up:

- It creates a tree object that will contain an entry for a *blob object*, held under the component-name `file.txt`.  This tree object will acquire a hash ID once it is created.  Let's call this hash ID *H<sub>2</sub>*.
- It creates another tree object that will contain an entry named `to`.  The entry for `to` will store hash ID *H<sub>2</sub>*.  (It may contain more entries: it will contain one for each other path that begins with `path/to/`.)  When `git write-tree` writes out this tree object, it will obtain a hash ID; let's call this hash ID *H<sub>1</sub>*.
- It then creates another tree object that will contain an entry named `path`, which will store hash ID *H<sub>1</sub>*.  (As before, it may contain more entries, such as one named `README.md` that will hold the hash ID of the blob containing the `README.md` file's content.)  When `git write-tree` writes out this tree object, it will obtain a hash ID, which we can call *H<sub>0</sub>*.

The `git write-tree` command reports this hash ID *H<sub>0</sub>* to its standard output.

The `git commit-tree` command uses this hash ID, plus additional information, to create a commit object.  The commit object will have *H<sub>0</sub>* as its `tree`.  Hence the commit will refer to tree *H<sub>0</sub>*.

To read the commit *into* Git's index, `git read-tree` notes that there is a sub-tree named `path` inside *H<sub>0</sub>*, so it reads that sub-tree (hash *H<sub>1</sub>*) and finds that there's an entry named `to` giving *H<sub>2</sub>*.  It therefore reads that sub-sub-tree and finds the entry named `file.txt` giving the blob hash ID for the file.  It then writes `path/to/file.txt` into the index, storing the hash ID for the blob object.

While `git commit` and `git checkout` now have all of these steps built into them, you can still use `git write-tree` followed by `git commit-tree` to make a new commit.  You can still use `git read-tree` to read a tree into Git's index, and then use `git checkout-index` to extract the files into a work-area.  The index has no directory names in it!  It has only file names.  The checkout code will just create new directories when needed: that is, if Git needs to create a file named `path/to/file.txt` and there is no `path` yet, Git will make it.  Now that there is a `path`, Git will make `path/to` as well if needed, and now that `path/to/` exists, Git can create a file named `file.txt` within `path/to/`.

The fact that Git doesn't store directories in the index means that:

- you have no way to store permissions for directories;<sup>1</sup> and
- there is no proper way to store an *empty* directory either.

There is a submodule trick that works for empty directories: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543445/1256452) to [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452)

---

<sup>1</sup>Since the only allowed *file* modes today are `100755` (executable) and `100644` (not-executable), there's no place to store group-write permission anyway.  In the early days of Git, you could store a file as mode `100664` for instance, so it would have made more sense then.  Note that on Linux, directories must be executable to use them, so while tree objects are stored as mode `40000`, the actual on-disk inode has mode `040777 & ~umask`, where `040000` is the `S_IFDIR` bit.  See, e.g., https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/include_2uapi_2linux_2stat_8h.html

Answer (score 3):

Git stores directories as `tree` objects which contain, for each entry in the directory, the mode, type, hash and name of the entry. For example, in a Git repository with a file and a folder at the root:

```
$ ls
example.txt
src/

$ git cat-file -p HEAD:
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    example.txt
040000 tree 87a2294c8c0351121cefbaef16cbe88dd2b64b80    src
```

The `cat-file` command shows the pretty (`-p`) version of the given object, `HEAD:`. The extra colon refers to the root directory of the branch. `HEAD:src` would refer to the `src` subfolder.

We can examine the raw directory data by passing `tree` instead of `-p`:

```
$ git cat-file tree HEAD: | hexdump  -C
00000000  31 30 30 36 34 34 20 65  78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e 74  |100644 example.t|
00000010  78 74 00 e6 9d e2 9b b2  d1 d6 43 4b 8b 29 ae 77  |xt........CK.).w|
00000020  5a d8 c2 e4 8c 53 91 34  30 30 30 30 20 73 72 63  |Z....S.40000 src|
00000030  00 87 a2 29 4c 8c 03 51  12 1c ef ba ef 16 cb e8  |...)L..Q........|
00000040  8d d2 b6 4b 80                                    |...K.|
```

If the git repository isn't packed, this tree object will be stored in `.git/objects`. We can use `rev-parse` to find its hash:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD:
cb8fd5fa2bf22ffa242d4e3fa520849551bbfa98
```

The zipped contents are the same data as above with a small prefix:

```
$ cat .git/objects/cb/8fd5fa2bf22ffa242d4e3fa520849551bbfa98 | zlib-flate -uncompress | hexdump -C
00000000  74 72 65 65 20 36 39 00  31 30 30 36 34 34 20 65  |tree 69.100644 e|
00000010  78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e 74  78 74 00 e6 9d e2 9b b2  |xample.txt......|
00000020  d1 d6 43 4b 8b 29 ae 77  5a d8 c2 e4 8c 53 91 34  |..CK.).wZ....S.4|
00000030  30 30 30 30 20 73 72 63  00 87 a2 29 4c 8c 03 51  |0000 src...)L..Q|
00000040  12 1c ef ba ef 16 cb e8  8d d2 b6 4b 80           |...........K.|
```

And we can confirm that the hash is correct:

```
$ cat .git/objects/cb/8fd5fa2bf22ffa242d4e3fa520849551bbfa98 | zlib-flate -uncompress | sha1sum
cb8fd5fa2bf22ffa242d4e3fa520849551bbfa98  -
```

See the "Tree Objects" section of [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for more information.